# Is 在瞬间 something like 'at some point'?

Tags: usage

The phrase 在瞬间 *zài shùnjiān* seems literally to mean 'in an instant'. But usage-wise, is it more like 'at some point'? Or am I off the mark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the better way to analyse "在瞬间" is to break it down to "在"+"瞬间" or even "在"+"瞬“+"间".

"瞬“ originally means "[the eye] opens and closes,  or, blinks". Because our eyes blink very quickly, this character extends to another meaning-"very short while, very short time period".

"间" means "the interval between two things[or time points]"

So "瞬间” literally means "the interval between the time points when the eyes opens and closes", OK, just means "very very short time period".

"在" is a preposition here and means "in", so "在瞬间“ means "in a very short while", "in an instant".You could also say,

> 我会在5分钟内回来。 *I will be back in 5 minutes.*
>   Here, "在5分钟内" has the same consruction as "在瞬间". You could say,
>   我会在瞬间回来 *I will be back in an instant.*
>   Ok, you would say it only when you have the magic power :D Just kidding.

Also, "瞬间” could be used as an adverb to mean "instantly, immediately"(=在瞬间 in this case).

> 我瞬间鼓起了勇气。 *I got up my nerve immediately.*

Comment: +1 and accept. all of the answers were good, but i only learned later (while conversing with someone who, while not a native speaker like you, has 20 years of experience speaking chinese) and they suggested doing the same thing: "在"+"瞬“+"间". the logic being that "在"+"X“+"间" influences the way the meaning works.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think 在瞬间 is used as often as 一瞬间， 瞬间，在那一瞬间，etc, which means **at that very moment**.

However, I can think of one situation where 在瞬间 can be perfectly used.

> 那座桥在瞬间崩塌了。

This sentence means *the bridge collapsed in no time*. So yes, 在瞬间 means *in an instant* in this case.

If you can provide more context, I'll be more than happy to follow up.

Comment: that's a perfect answer without context, actually. thanks for the broad range of usage examples.

Answer (score 4):

I have never heard it used to mean "at some point." As far as I know, it always means "instantly" and is used to describe something which happens in the space of a brief moment. One illustrative phrase is "瞬间即逝" (shùnjiānjíshì), "to disappear (in the blink of an eye)." Indeed, 瞬 itself is quite close to the meaning of the English phrase "the blink of an eye" and 瞬间 preserves that sense.